# Correct way to add dynamic form fields to WagtailModelAdminForm

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I have a use case where I need to add dynamic form fields to a `WagtailModelAdminForm`. With standard django I would normally just create a custom subclass and add the fields in the `__init__` method of the form. In Wagtail, because the forms are built up with the edit_handlers, this becomes a nightmare to deal with.

I have the following dynamic form:

```py
class ProductForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = get_product_model()
        exclude = ['attributes', 'state', 'variant_of']

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if self.instance:
            self.inject_attribute_fields()

    def inject_attribute_fields(self):
        for k, attr in self.instance.attributes.items():
            field_klass = None
            field_data = attr.get("input")
            field_args = {
                'label': field_data['name'],
                'help_text': field_data['help_text'],
                'required': field_data['is_required'],
                'initial': attr['value'],
            }

            if 'choices' in field_data:
                field_args['choices'] = (
                    (choice["id"], choice["value"])
                    for choice in field_data['choices']
                )

                if field_data['is_multi_choice']:
                    field_klass = forms.MultipleChoiceField
                else:
                    field_klass = forms.ChoiceField
            else:
                typ = field_data['attr_type']
                if typ == 'text':
                    field_klass = forms.CharField

                elif typ == 'textarea':
                    field_klass = forms.CharField
                    field_args['widget'] = forms.Textarea

                elif typ == 'bool':
                    field_klass = forms.BooleanField

                elif typ == 'int':
                    field_klass = forms.IntegerField

                elif typ == 'decimal':
                    field_klass = forms.DecimalField

                elif typ == 'date':
                    field_klass = forms.DateField
                    field_args['widget'] = AdminDateInput

                elif typ == 'time':
                    field_klass = forms.TimeField
                    field_args['widget'] = AdminTimeInput

                elif typ == 'datetime':
                    field_klass = forms.DateTimeField
                    field_args['widget'] = AdminDateTimeInput

            if field_klass is None:
                raise AttributeError('Cannot create widgets for invalid field types.')

            # Create the custom key
            self.fields[f"attributes__{k}"] = field_klass(**field_args)
```

Next I customized the ModelAdmin `EditView` (attributes are not present in the create view):

```py
class EditProductView(EditView):
    def get_edit_handler(self):
        summary_panels = [
            FieldPanel('title'),
            FieldPanel('description'),
            FieldPanel('body'),
        ]

        # NOTE: Product attributes are dynamic, so we generate them
        attributes_panel = get_product_attributes_panel(self.instance)

        variants_panel = []
        if self.instance.is_variant:
            variants_panel.append(
                InlinePanel(
                    'stockrecords',
                    classname="collapsed",
                    heading="Variants & Prices"
                )
            )
        else:
            variants_panel.append(ProductVariantsPanel())

          return TabbedInterface([
            ObjectList(summary_panels, heading='Summary'),
            
            # This panel creates dynamic panels related to the dynamic form fields,
            # but raises an error saying that the "fields are missing".
            # Understandable because it's not present on the original model
            # ObjectList(attributes_panel, heading='Attributes'),

            ObjectList(variants_panel, heading='Variants'),
            ObjectList(promote_panels, heading='Promote'),
            ObjectList(settings_panels, heading='Settings'),
        ], base_form_class=ProductForm).bind_to_model(self.model_admin.model)
```

Here is the `get_product_attributes_panel()` function for reference:

```py
def get_product_attributes_panel(product) -> list:
    panels = []
    for key, attr in product.attributes.items():
        widget = None
        field_name = "attributes__" + key
        attr_type = attr['input'].get('attr_type')

        if attr_type == 'date':
            widget = AdminDateInput()

        elif attr_type == 'datetime':
            widget = AdminDateTimeInput()

        else:
            if attr_type is None and 'choices' in attr['input']:
                if attr['input']['is_multi_choice']:
                    widget = forms.SelectMultiple
                else:
                    widget = forms.Select
            else:
                widget = forms.TextInput()

        if widget:
            panels.append(FieldPanel(field_name, widget=widget))
        else:
            panels.append(FieldPanel(field_name))

    return panels
```

So the problem is...

A) Adding the ProductForm in the way I did above (by using it as the base_form_class in TabbedInterface) *almost works*; It adds the fields to the form; BUT I have no control over the rendering.

B) If I *uncomment* the line `ObjectList(attributes_panel, heading='Attributes'),` (to get nice rendering of the fields), then I get an error for my dynamic fields, saying that they are missing.

This is a very important requirement in the project I'm working on.

A temporary workaround is to create a **custom panel** to render the dynamic fields directly in the html template; But then I lose the Django Form validation, which is also an important requirement for this.

Is there any way to add dynamic fields the the WagtailModelAdminForm, that **preserves** the modeladmin features such as formsets, permissions etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a separate `AttributeForm` for the attributes.

A custom Panel then looks for this new form instance as an attribute of the primary form. As an instance on the primary form, I can "clean" this internal form when the primary form `clean()` is called and, raise any errors that I need to on both forms.

I then customized the `EditView.post()` method to make sure that I add the instance of `AttributesForm` to our primary model form.

It's a bit of a workaround, but works well enough for now. I wish there was an easier way, but it doesn't look like it right now.